# Need help with SQL subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, select, substring

what i need is to be albe to select all the fields information from a table, where the name of the field from another table called "field_(and a number)"

i've tryed things like that but it didn't work...

```
SELECT  * 
FROM  `fieldList` 
WHERE ID =  "(SUBSTRING(SHOW FIELDS,5) FROM formList_5 LIKE  'field_%')"
```

and

```
SELECT  * 
FROM  `fieldList` 
WHERE ID =  "SUBSTRING((SHOW FIELDS FROM formList_5 LIKE  'field_%'),5)"
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: Once upon a time there was concern on separating structure from data...

Comment: Can you give the table structures, some sample data, and some expected output? This also sounds like perhaps one of the worst-designed databases that I've heard of in a long time. What Adrian says is true.

Comment: actually it's just that i forgot 1 field and cannot go back, it's a form DB in 3 parts, the main one contain all infos of the different forms. the 2nd one takes all the infos that peoples submit and the final one is used to include informations on each fields (ie: field title, field name, price etc... my plan was to make some kind of bill with it (what they chose) but as i said, i messed up my field_ID and cannot change back everything since there's already some entries.   ain't THAT messed up...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you need:

```
SELECT *
FROM   `fieldlist`
WHERE  id IN (SELECT SUBSTRING(column_name, 5)
              FROM   information_schema.columns
              WHERE  table_name = 'formList_5'
              AND    column_name LIKE 'field_%')
```

But, for sanity's sake, review your DB design if you can.

Comment: OMG THANKS! exactly what i needed!

sadly i cannot make + since i don't have 15 rep... but Thanks a lot!